onnxruntime use python api load onnx model with onnx_data
Using the Python API of ONNX Runtime to load ONNX models larger than 2GB, these models usually have external data to support their size.
However, no sources were found on how to use this additional data in the ONNX Runtime API.
for example, metric model https://huggingface.co/onnx-community/metric3d-vit-large/tree/main
i found some useful doc, but in c++?  https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/tutorials/web/large-models.html
